# Save Figure to new Image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I've done removal lines from image and I want to save (figure) it into a new image.

Line is removed:

[image: Filled by White Rectangle]

So here's my code.

```
clc;              % Clear the command window.
close all;        % Close all figures (except those of imtool.)
imtool close all; % Close all imtool figures if you have the Image Processing Toolbox.
clear;            % Erase all existing variables. Or clearvars if you want.
workspace;        % Make sure the workspace panel is showing.
format short g;
format compact;
fontSize = 20;

grayImage = imread('tab1.png');
% Save this figure handle.
hFig1 = gcf;
% Get the dimensions of the image.  
% numberOfColorBands should be = 1.
[rows, columns, numberOfColorBands] = size(grayImage);
if numberOfColorBands > 1
    % It's not really gray scale like we expected - it's color.
    % Convert it to gray scale by taking only the green channel.
    grayImage = grayImage(:, :, 2); % Take green channel.
end

binaryImage = grayImage < 240;
binaryImage(: ,1: 20) = false;
imshow(grayImage, []);
hold on;
cc = bwconncomp(binaryImage);
% Measure the bounding box of all blobs.
measurements = regionprops(cc, 'BoundingBox');
fprintf('Found %d regions\n', cc.NumObjects);
numSkinnyRegions = 0;
bboxes=cat(1,measurements.BoundingBox);
for k = 1 : cc.NumObjects
    figure(hFig1); % Switch to figure 1.
    print(gcf,'Figuree','-dpng');
    thisBB = measurements(k).BoundingBox
    % Draw a box around the region in cyan.
    hRect = rectangle('Position', thisBB, 'EdgeColor', 'c', 'LineWidth', 1);
    aspectRatio(k) = thisBB(4)/thisBB(3);
    if (thisBB(4) <= 3 || thisBB(3) <= 3) && (aspectRatio(k) > 4 || aspectRatio(k) < 1/4)
        numSkinnyRegions = numSkinnyRegions + 1;
        % Save it to a cell array, just in case we want to use it after the loop is done.
        croppedImages{numSkinnyRegions} = imcrop(binaryImage, thisBB);      
        % Draw skinny regions in a different color
        delete(hRect); % Get rid of old one.
        hRect = rectangle('Position', thisBB);
        hRect.FaceColor = 'w';
        hRect.EdgeColor = 'w';
        hRect.LineWidth = 2;
   end
end

figure; imshow(grayImage)
```

When I save the figure into a png file, the result is the image contained a black lines, different from what i got in figure.
[saved image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcSWV.png).

So what's wrong from my code? Did I put the code `print(gcf,'Figuree','-dpng');` in a wrong line?

Comment: Remove lines in the sense? You want to remove those lines in the Original image?

Comment: yep. Is it possible?

Comment: You've already done the removal, just save the new image?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Can you clarify?

Comment: You have already removed the lines. right ? Are you unable to save the image ?

Answer (score -1):

Ok now i got my own answer! Just use `export_fig` from [mathworks file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig). Cheers!

Comment: Ok thanks for your suggestion Mark. I'll edit it soon.

Comment: Why are you saving an image from a figure that has probably been rescaled/resampled, reducing the accuracy of any future processing, instead of just saving `grayimage` that contains all of your data already?

Comment: because i save the process in figure (hfig1 = gcf) not directly in image.

Comment: Now this is essentially a link-only answer, not something SO really likes.